# Pass along get params?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use ajax to retrieve some JSON from another page, but I want to pass along the same GET params that were used to request the original page. How do I do that? Does JS store them in a dict somewhere? Or is there a jQuery solution?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'mysecretwebpage.com/supersecret',
    data: ???
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get QueryString values with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

The data you need you'll find in

```
window.location.search
```

Remove the first char from this string(will be the question mark, if GET is not empty)

Comment: I also want to add a value... I can append it to the string, but what if it already exists? I'd need to replace it.

Comment: Ususally it does'nt matter. If you append a key onto a QUERY_STRING, which is already inside, only the last occurance should be considered by the recipient. Assuming a QUERY_STRING like `a=1&a=2&a=3` on the serverside GET['a'] will be 3

Answer (score 2):

I got this handy function:

```
document.getParameterByName = function (name) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
  if (results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
};
```

Use it like:

```
var paramValue = document.getParameterByName('paramName');
```

Comment: Don't really want a single param name... I want a dict. And I'm pretty sure you yoinked that off the net somewhere.. at least link back to the article you stole it from.

Answer (score 1):

turns out [this has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery/2880929#2880929)